# Merge the "font" and "fonts" tags

Tags: discussion, tags

A 'plural tag' merge request:

- [font](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font) — 177 tagged, 39 this year, 5 this month

  > A font (more accurately a typeface) is the visual appearance, representation or interpretation of a set of characters, typically alphanumeric as a minimum.
- [fonts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fonts) — 44 tagged, 13 this year

  > *no tag wiki/excerpt*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done - I resisted the urge to merge into [typeface](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typeface) or other term and also merged font-rendering into the base tag... :-)